# Declaring variable in "data" section as an alias to $root is not reactive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I declare variable in **main.js**:

```
data: {
  globalData: {}
}
```

I want to avoid using `this.$root.globalData` all the time — so I use local variable in a component as an alias to "global variable":

```
data() {
  return {
    localAlias: this.$root.globalData,
  }
}
```

Then I fetch global variable from a server in **main.js** (simulate by `setTimeout`):

```
create() {
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    this.globalData = {a:1, b:2};
  }, 1500);
}
```

And `localAlias` remains equal to initial value.

How to make it work? I don't need Vuex yet, I just grab data from server and use it read-only.

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/kww47l2j0o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `data` you can use `computed`. It will solve your problem.

```
computed: {
    localAlias: function() {
      return this.$root.globalData;
    }
  }
```

I have updated the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/1qlonw9p8j)

Answer (score 0):

The reason localAlias doesn't change is because it still points to the same object, while you re-point this.$root.globalData to a new object. One way to do it is of course to use computed as the other answer suggested. Another way to solve it it to just change the properties instead of re-binding the entire object:

```
create() {
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    this.globalData.a = 1;
    this.globalData.b = 2;
  }, 1500);
}
```

This is less versatile though and will scale worse if the object becomes bigger.